MSOL framing of max-flow probem
Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with edge capacities $c_e$ for each $e\in E$, a source $s\in V$ and destination $t\in V$, how do I frame the max-flow problem in MSOL?

You are likely familiar with the Max Flow–Min Cut theorem which states that the maximum $s$-$t$-flow in $G$ is equivalent to the minimum $s$-$t$-cut in $G$.  You can define a property in $\textsf{MSOL}$ called (e.g.) $\text{conn}(G, s, t, C)$ which is true if there is a path from $s$ to $t$ in $G-C$, where $C$ is a set of edges.

But how do we account for non-unit edge capacities

Is this a homework question? Or a question from somewhere specific? If so, please cite your sources.

No, it is not a homework question. I am trying to understand MSOL (in the context of using Treewidth, Courcelle's theorem etc.). I want to just be able to write a well-understood problem like max-flow in terms of MSOL.

I don't think it's possible (but I could be wrong) without resorting to one of the weighted variants of MSOL.

Okay. Max-flow is any way poly-time solvable. But, does this mean we don't know of an algorithm to solve weighted versions of stable-set problems even on graphs with bounded treewidth, using Courcelle's theorem? Only the unweighted version can be solved? Or is there a work around?

That's correct, Courcelle's theorem can in that situation not be used.

Ps, you have CMSOL that can do counting modulo some fixed number, but again, not usable for the general version of Weighted Independent Set.
